# How to change source of iFrame gracefully

Tags: html, iframe

I am able to load new content into an iFrame using

$('#iframeID').attr('src','newUrl').

But the new source takes ~1-2 seconds to load which causes the shift to be abrupt. Is there a way to make the change gracefully?

I want to retain the old content till the new content is loaded and replace the old content with the new content after it gets loaded.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please! Provide us with JSFIDDLES! 
Anyway, try to use .fadeIn(1000) with your code?
`$('#iframeID').attr('src','newUrl').fadeIn(1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Try AngularJs.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

You can load content into a div. It has animations while including the html and you can subscribe events to it.

```
[div ng-include src="'views/sidepanel.html'"]
    here comes my include
[/div]
```

Here is a Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/MfHa6/